# TableView datasource value updation issue

Tags: swift, tableview

i have an app in which user can search location from search bar. When user search any location the results are shown in the table view under the search bar. Issue is coming that when i search any location it gives that the result but does not show in table view. I have check delegate and datasource they are properly attached but still table view doesn't showing any data in it. How can i get that data in table view. I have used breakpoint also it is not catching the break point. This is the code how i'm getting search results,

```
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    guard let mapView = mapView,
        let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    print(searchBarText)
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
    request.region = mapView.region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    print(search)
    search.start { response, _ in
        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }
        self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
        print(self.matchingItems)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here i'm passing the search results to the table view,

```
extension LocationSearchTable {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return matchingItems.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    print(  cell.textLabel?.text)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
    print( cell.detailTextLabel?.text)
    return cell
}
```

}
This is the response that comes when i search any location,

```
[<MKMapItem: 0x1c434d5d0> {
isCurrentLocation = 0;
name = California;
placemark = "California, California, United States @ <+37.13374180,-120.28640480> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+37.41896824,-119.30660700> radius 706259.58', center:<+37.41896824,-119.30660700>, radius:706259.58m)";
timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles (GMT-7) offset -25200 (Daylight)";
```

}]

This is whole code for my swift file,

```
// weak var delegate: HandleMapSearch?
var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = []
var mapView: MKMapView?
 func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {

    // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
    let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil &&
                        selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""

    // put a comma between street and city/state
    let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) &&
                (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""

    // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
    let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil &&
                        selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""

    let addressLine = String(
        format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
        // street number
        selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
        firstSpace,
        // street name
        selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
        comma,
        // city
        selectedItem.locality ?? "",
        secondSpace,
        // state
        selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
    )

    return addressLine
}
```

Comment: Do `self.matchingItems = response.mapItems; self.tableView.reloadData()` in main thread?

Comment: let me try @Larme

Comment: still not it is showing the results. @Larme

Comment: which swift version you  use , Also can   include complete code

Comment: i'm using swift4.1 version. and check it i have updated my code. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate and dataSource in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

and implement the methods correctly like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {t {
    return matchingItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    print(  cell.textLabel?.text)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
    print( cell.detailTextLabel?.text)
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return 100
}
```

Comment: compiler is showing me suggestion to override for numberOfRowsInSection function. @Sh_Khan

Comment: app is crashing when i search any location. This is the crash error,  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x1588ea200; frame = (0 0; 414 736); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c3649630>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c1026f40>; contentOffset: {0, -56}; contentSize: {414, 44}; adjustedContentInset: {56, 0, 226, 0}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Comment: no need for override in swift 4.1  , also copy the methods as i added them in answer

Comment: It is crashing on line 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! This is the error it is showing,
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . @Sh_Khan